# Heroku CLI alternative download location

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to download heroku CLI following this guide:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

The address provided of 
https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz gives 403 errors.

I'm wondering if anyone else has a copy of this file that they can share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another address:
[https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh) in https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh file.

You can run this command for standalone

`wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh`

If you using Ubuntu/Debian:

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```