# How to install Heroku CLI on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, raspberry-pi3

**THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED READ ANSWER BELOW ON HOW TO DOWNLOAD HEROKU CLI ON RPI3**

Just saying. Sorry if this has been asked before - I coudnt find it.

I have a Raspberry PI 3 and I am trying to install Heroku CLI. If I try to do it the normal way, for ubuntu or linux, it fails.[Can't install Heroku CLI on Raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189549/cant-install-heroku-cli-on-raspbian) dosent wokr becasue i get error

```
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz
```

> --2018-05-23 17:15:46--  https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz
>   Resolving cli-assets.heroku.com (cli-assets.heroku.com)... 54.230.9.187, 54.230.9.194, 54.230.9.84, ...
>   Connecting to cli-assets.heroku.com (cli-assets.heroku.com)|54.230.9.187|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
>   2018-05-23 17:15:50
>   ERROR 404: Not Found.

This post however dosent work either  [Heroku CLI alternative download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203702/heroku-cli-alternative-download-location)
and returns error

```
    gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dpkg: error processing package heroku (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of heroku-toolbelt:
 heroku-toolbelt depends on heroku (= 3.99.4); however:
  Package heroku is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package heroku-toolbelt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 heroku
 heroku-toolbelt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when i run the command

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Heroku CLI on Raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189549/cant-install-heroku-cli-on-raspbian)

Comment: @Dalton Cézane i explained  why its not duplicate

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203702/heroku-cli-alternative-download-location

Comment: @DaltonCézane Dosent work either i willl show error output in above post

Comment: @botbotbotty, it looks like you're literally requesting `https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz`. The comment in the accepted answer on the question that Dalton first suggested says, 'Replace OS with one of “linux”, “darwin”, “windows”, “freebsd”, “openbsd”', and 'Replace ARCH with one of “amd64”, “386” or “arm”'. Did you do that?

Comment: @Chris Wow! I must have been blind then. Will try again

Comment: @Chris Also does it matter if i use amd64 or 386 or arm(new to Heroku)

Comment: @botbotbotty, that refers to the architecture of your local machine. For a Raspberry Pi I believe you want `arm`.

Comment: @Chris still getting errors following thos instructions i get this error when i run heroku --version

Comment: its bash: /usr/local/bin/heroku: No such file or directory

Comment: @Chris It is fine now it was a sudo permision error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @botbotbotty, I'm glad you got this working. Now that you've figured out all of the moving parts, please consider [posting your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with all the details. This may help other users in the future.

Comment: will do when i have some more time

Comment: @Chris , apparently it was really a duplicated question. I do not think it has to have an answer, since it will be fundamentally the same. Don't you agree?

Comment: @DaltonCézane, probably, but that requires more close votes. In case that doesn't happen I'd prefer to have an answer here. And there may be slight differences with botbotbotty's situation; I'm curious about the `sudo` issue they mention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**OK guys i figured it out. If the posts above didnt work for you this is how to do it**
This is how you install Heroku CLI onto a raspberry pi 3

Step 1: Make sure you have sudo privilages. The default RPI3 account has sudo so you need not worry about this If you cant get sudo privilages you may still be able to download the CLI .

**How to check if you have sudo enabled**
run these following commands from terminal

```
sudo su
```

If you have sudo privileges the terimal should now say

```
root@ControlUnit:/home/[Your account name]
```

or something along those lines.
then run `exit` then continue with steps
If it does continue with the next steps.
If not- if you own RPI3 then login into the default account(password: raspberry) and do `sudo adduser [yourname] -g sudo`. If you do not own it ask the owner to do this

**Sudo aside**
This is how you do the heroku CLI:
**Run the following commands**

```
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-linux-arm.tar.gz
```

what this does is it installs a outdated copy(you can update it later) made for the Raspberry Pi. Then run this command

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
```

This is the part where you have to use sudo. If you cant use sudo still try the commands.

```
sudo tar -xvzf heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
```

Then just make sure you  have it run in the terminal

```
heroku version
```

or `heroku --version`

it should come up saying something along the lines of

```
heroku-cli/5.7.1-c574890 (linux-arm) go1.7.5
```

then run

```
heroku update
```

and your done!

**COPY PASTE COMMANDS***

> wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-linux-arm.tar.gz
>
> mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
>
> sudo tar -xvzf heroku-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
>
> heroku update

Comment: I did that and got an ```/home/berry/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: line 29: /home/berry/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/node: No such file or directory```

Comment: Updating the client broke it by throwing a segmentation fault

Comment: Just to add to this, trying to do this today on a Raspberry Pi 4. This approach (and others posted online) currently fail, I believe, because Heroku CLI now requires nodejs version 14+, and the version distributed on PiOS (64-bit) is 12. Possibly solvable by using nvm to upgrade nodejs, but I've not gone that step. The path of least resistance for me has been to find workrounds for deployment from a Pi, e.g. use Github deployment instead of 'heroku create'. Once deployed, the app can be managed using the CLI running on Windows

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `sudo tar -xvzf heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib` as noted in the original post, the correct command should be `sudo tar -xvzf **heroku-linux-arm.tar.gz** -C /usr/local/lib`